# Kubernetes: Same node but different IPs

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have created a K8s cluster on GCP, and I deployed an application.

Then I scaled it:

> kubectl scale deployment hello-world-rest-api --replicas=3

Now when I run 'kubectl get pods', I see three pods. Their NODE value is same. I understand it means they all are deployed on same machine. But I observe that IP value for all three is different.

If NODE is same, then why is IP different?

Comment: can you provide the service definition over the deployment with which these pods were created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several networks in a k8s cluster. The pods are on the pod network, so every pod deployed on the nodes of a k8s cluster can see each other as though they are independent nodes on a network. The pod address space is different from the node address space. So, each pod running on a node gets a unique address from the pod network, which is also different from the node network. The k8s components running on each node perform the address translation.